# solving equations involving algebraic functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In some research I am involved in, we frequently hit on equations involving algebraic functions.   Note that I am using this term in the classical sense (as explicated, e.g., in the classical text of Hardy " Introduction to pure mathematics"), that is, not polynomials but functions involving roots.  The equations I encounter are low dimensional systems, typically five or less equations in functions of the corresponding number of dimensions variables.  They also involve only square roots.  Indirect evidence suggests that there is some general theory about the nature of such zero sets as in algebraic geometry for polynomials (I am thinking of results  such as Bezout's theorem).  In simple cases, one can square out to reduce to polynomial equations but this only works occasionally.  A major problem in trying to trace any theory is that search machines seem to equate "algebraic functions" with polynomials. I would be very grateful for any references about a general theory in this direction.  The classical monographs on algebraic functions (e.g., by Artin) seems to discuss the univariate case and to concern themselves with other questions.

Comment: If you have a system of equations involving radicals, such as $\sqrt{f(x)}$ with $f(x)$ some polynomial, you can replace $\sqrt{f(x)}$ by a new variable $y$ and add the equation $y^2 =f(x)$. So there is no loss of generality in dealing only with systems of polynomial equations. Having said that, I voted to migrate this question to math.stackexchange, where I think it is better placed.

Comment: The radicals in an algebraic function apply to expressions in the independent variables not the dependent ones.  The term is standard, if, perhaps, no longer common knowledge but  I did refer to two texts by eminent mathematicisns (both easily available on line) where it is described precisely.  Please read them before removing  my query before people who understand it have a chance to respond.